# jPicker jQuery Color Picker Plugin

Tags: jquery, jpicker

I am using jPicker to dynamically create pickers as and when needed. Is there a way to open it on creation? Something like `$.jPicker.List[index].show();`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can call the show method on the jPicker like this:

```
$("#someid").jPicker("show");
```